# Intercept user interaction on a webview (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uitapgesturerecognizer, user-interaction

I need to intercept user interaction on my ViewController (in Swift). 
My ViewController is fully covered by a webview.

**To intercept user touching the screen I've implemented 2 methods**

First method:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    println("ue")
}
```

Second method:

```
var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "refreshWebview")
    self.webView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Now, both methods work if I touch in a area where there isn't the webview. But if I click on the area of the webview both methods do not work.

Surfing the web I've noticed that I am not the only one having this problem and looking for an answer. But I couldn't find a working answer to this problem: there are a lot of useless answers, others in objective-c, others that are incomplete...

So I'm asking, anybody had this problem and could help me? 
Please.. do not answer with another stackoverflow discussions because trust to me when I tell you that I've already checked every topic...

Thank you

Comment: Is userInteraction Enabled on your webView?
Can you show us your refreshWebView?

Comment: Hi! Yes it is enabled and the "refreshWebView" just prints "hello" :)

Comment: Try using the Objective-C answers rather than asking for others to do the translation for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can receive a `touch event` by using [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp) and then forward the event to objC. Check this [How to Properly Call ObjectiveC From Javascript](http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/)